# Schedule a bug export from TFS

Tags: team-foundation-server, task, schedule

Is there any way that I can schedule a bug export from TFS. I have my query all set up and can manually export to excel - ideally I want to be able to run this export every night to a csv file sat on a networked disk.

Is there any way of doing this, either within TFS or with Task Scheduler etc?

Answer (score 1):

To export the query to Excel, you need to initiate the command from Excel. Probably it is possible, but it is not easy.

Another option is to create a PowerShell script or Console application that reads the result of the query and writes the result in a csv file.

A last option is to use reporting services. You don't have a work item query then, but you create a new report that reads from the TFS warehouse and exports the results to CSV (there is in SSRS a scheduling engine you can leverage)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this help you

```
tfpt query /collection:https://myserver:8443/tfs/Default "Project\My Queries\Android Bug&Change Request List for Release Notes" /format:tsv >c:\test.txt
```